# PowerDNS Authoritative and Recursor together on one host

Tags: networking, domain-name-system, powerdns

Is it possible to run a PowerDNS Authoritative Server and PowerDNS Recursor on the same host?
Or do i need to make a specific host for Authoritative and a specific host for being a Recursor.